# Implementing an interactive R console in c# / rdotnet?

Tags: c#, r

I'm adding statistical processing to a C# app using rdotnet, which looks ideal for our current needs. Basically, the app generates lots of different time series, and we use R to calculate distributions, quantiles etc.

What would be great for a future version would be if we could add an interactive R console to the app, so that the user can perform further ad hoc processing on the data within the app environment.

Initial research hasn't thrown up any pointer or examples. Can anyone suggest a way forward ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capturing the R Console I/O and show it in a console is possible, but making it interactive may not be possible. You will find more details in [this discussion post](http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/458634) and the links it has to other posts. The post also has alternate solutions proposed; basically where the R console is the main application and loads/shows your C# application.

Comment: Thanks, that will get me stareted...would upvote but not reputable enough....

Comment: Following j-m's suggested link has led me to start implementing an ICharacterDevice, based on [Simple.Wpf.Terminal](https://github.com/oriches/Simple.Wpf.Terminal)